# Angular submitting multiple checkboxes and getting submitted data in a specific format

Tags: angularjs

Hi i've got the following json structure and i am trying to build multiple checkboxes from this using a checkbox directive in angular.

```
{
    "selected":"",
    "selectReportingYears":[
        {
            "report_date_year":2016
        },
        {
            "report_date_year":2017
        },
        {
            "report_date_year":2018
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
{
    "selected":"",
    "selectInsurerType":[
        {
            "insurer_type_name": "Composite"
        },
        {
            "insurer_type_name":"Life"
        },
        {
            "insurer_type_name":"Random"
        }
    ]
}
```

so when i submit the values i want the submitted data in angular in a specific format.

```
{"report_date_year":[2016, 2018], "insurer_type_name":["composite", "life"]}
```

and so on. I already have a directive that does an ng-repeat and displays the options with the checkboxes. Its just the submit bit and getting to submit the right format i am stuck with. Any help is much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<form id="filterForm" class="content-form" method="post">
    <label>Reporting Year</label>
    <checkbox-builder table="selectReportingYears" field="report_date_year"></checkbox-builder>
    <button ng-click="submitQuery()" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Directive Template

```
<label ng-repeat="value in selectdata[table]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ table }}" value="{{ value[field] }}" ng-model="value[field]]">
    {{ value[field] }}
</label>
```

Angular Directive code

```
tables.directive('checkboxBuilder', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            table: '@table',
            field: '@field'
        },

        controller: "tablesCtrl",
        templateUrl: 'assets/templates/angular/checkbox-field.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.getSelectData(scope.table);
        }
    };
});
```

Do let me know if you need further info. Thanks.

Comment: Pls put dom template

Comment: and what is in 'submitQuery'? You can put any logic there...

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, submitQuery is where the fields will be submitted and i'll have some extra login in there.